# What is the traditional order that Districts are visited?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In Catching Fire, the Victory Tour starts with District 12, then goes down to 11, and seemingly in order to end at the Capital. Of course, that makes sense for a victor in District 12, but what would happen if, say, a District 4 won? Would the order be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the order is the same.

> It [the Victory Tour] begins in District 12 and then goes in descending order to District 1, followed by the Capitol. The winner's district is skipped and saved for last. Like the Games, the tour is televised. [More information on the Victory Tour and the Hunger Games Trilogy](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_Tour)

Comment: "The winner's district is skipped and saved for last." maybe it's just me, but it would appear your answer contradicts itself?

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister It doesn't contradict itself. From what I remember, it goes in descending order of districts from 12 to 1 but skips the winner's district, then they go to the Capitol, then finally they go to their own district (where they move into a huge house, are given lots of money and live miserably ever after).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - it does contradict itself. You said "the order is the same". If it skips the winner's district and comes back to it, then the order is actually DIFFERENT from year to year depending on which district the winner is from. This after all is actually what the original question asked.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister I didn't say anything, it's not my answer. I was also just looking at the quote, didn't notice the text above it. You're right, the "Yes, the order is the same." is contradicted by the quote.

Comment: @Anthony Grist - apologies. they really should make the name of the answer-poster bigger so myopic peeps like me know exactly who to address ;)

Comment: By "The order is the same" I meant that it always goes in descending order from 12 to 1. I didn't mean for it to contradict itself, sorry, I just got my wording scrambled.

Answer (score 1):

To quote directly from the book:

> **Usually it kicks off in 12 and then goes in descending district order to 1, followed by the Capitol. The victor's district is skipped and saved for very last.** Since 12 puts on the least fabulous celebration — usually just a dinner for the tributes and a victory rally in the square, where nobody looks like they're having any fun — it's probably best to get us out of the way as soon as possible. This year, for the first time since Haymitch won, the final stop on the tour will be 12, and the Capitol will spring for the festivities. (*Catching Fire*, chapter 4)

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

No it wasn't. It always started from District 12, and moved towards district 1. However, the district that won was always visited last. The celebrations at the Capitol took place after that.